# what is the best way to convert a char array (without null termination) to string

Tags: c++, stl

I have a char array with known size (say 10) and I want to convert it to a strng. The main point is the array is not NULL terminated so this technique that used in the following sample code can not be used.

```
char arr[ ] = "This is a test";

string str(arr);
```

I can do this:

```
 char * array=getArray();
 string output;
 for(int I=0;i<10;i++)
 {
    output.append(array[I]);
 }
```

or even better one is:

```
 char * array=getArray();
 string output;
  output.append(10,array);
```

But is there any better way to do this?

Comment: How does the first code sample fail to "work"?

Comment: See constructor #5 at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/ It takes a `char*` and a length.

Comment: @juanchopanza It is not failing, just asking for a better, cleaner way to do this? Please note that in my case, the array is not NULL terminated, but the first sample code is based on a null terminated array.

Comment: You shouldn't write "this code doesn't work" followed by code that works.

Comment: Basically, the code in your question should be an actual example of the problem. Don't say you have an array of size 10 with no null terminator, and then post an example of an array with size 15 that DOES have a null terminator.

Comment: @juanchopanza changed the question to stress that the technique can not used and the code is correct for the sample.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't have a nul-terminated string, but you know its length, you can use either the two iterator constructor:

```
string str(arr, arr + len);
```

or the appropriate count constructor:

```
string str(arr, len);
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `"This is a test"` *is* `NIL`-terminated and the first sample just works - the compiler implicitly stores string literals with zero termination.

If your array really is not `NIL`-terminated, the third approach will be good while the second is rather inefficient because it appends piecewise. `std::string` also has a constructor that takes a count: `std::string(array, 10)`.